# is there something like dynamic or adaptive thresholding in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I need to find blobs in a range of grayscale images. This seems to be an easy task with thresholding using OpenCV, so I am doing these basic steps:

```py
# get 'gray' image from previous step ...
bias = 1.5
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
thresh, bin_img = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, bin_img = cv2.threshold(blurred, thresh * bias, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

First I calculate a "good" thresholding value using the Otsu algorithm, then I perform the final thresholding operation based on that otsu result * a custom bias value. This basically works well, howver, I noticed that the value I need for `bias` very much depends on the image I am processing.

Here are two examples. In the first one the otsu result is fine, so I can set `bias` to 1.0 - using a higher `bias` value removes too much of the blob:

[image: First example]

However, as you can see in this second example, here I need to set `bias` to 3.0, which leads to a perfect result - using a `bias` value below 3.0 leaves too much noise in the image:

[image: Second example]

Now, is there some way to "dynamically" adjust this `bias` value (using some sort of computer vision algorithm), so that I would always get that optimal result? Or is this something only the human eye+brain can do, and I would need some kind of deep learning or other "intelligent" approach for this?

For your reference, some (more) example images [can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMAm0.jpg).

Comment: Have you tried adaptiveThreshold?  See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3

Comment: a "bias" is something additive. you've got a *factor* there. -- otsu minimizes the variance of each segment (0, 1). if you need something else, you'll need to investigate your data and your subjective sensibilities as to what is "desired", and how to express that robustly and executably. perhaps start by staring at __histograms__

Comment: One common way is to normalize the images, e.g. by stretching min and max values to 0..255, but it strongly depends on the domain and on capturing modalities, whether such a way will work for you.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Well, my "desire" is to find those bright blobs as shown in my examples, and at the same time ignore the other brighter areas on the images. I have played with histograms, but those bright pixels seem to share similar color values, as can be seen in the examples linked.

Comment: what distinguishes the main blob from the others? sure, they differ in brightness, so that's something to work with... -- source data (not screenshots of plots) would help. also: what are these pictures (of), how are they made, ...